# getting x and y coordinate everywhere on the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, coordinate

i would like to know how can i get x,y coordinate on every click, in every place on the page.
I want to use the div's but i dont know how to modify it.
Thanks.
It only shows x,y coordinates whille i click the pharagraph.
this is my code:

```
<script>
 function show_coords(event)
 {
 var x=event.clientX;
 var y=event.clientY;
 alert("X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y);
 }
 </script>

 <div id="x">x</div>
 <div id="y">y</div>
 <p onmousedown="show_coords(event)">Click this paragraph, and an alert box will alert the x and y coordinates of the mouse pointer.</p>
```

Comment: Note that `event.clientX` and `event.clientY` give you the coordinates relative to the top-left corner of the browser window, **not** the page itself.  So if you click on the same part of the page before and after scrolling the window to a different location, you'll get different results.  [See here for more info.](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/mouseclickeventcoordinates.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the same event to body

```
<body onmousedown="show_coords(event)">
....
</body>
```

To elaborate more for question owner on why it does not work on entire "window" yet:
Your body is not covering the entire window. Just the div element and that is why you stll get same result. make the body to occupy full window. See below sample:-

```
<html>
<head>
<title>sample</title>
<style>
body {
 border : 2px solid red;
 overflow : true;
 width : 100% ;
 height : 100%;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_coords(event) {
 var x=event.clientX;
 var y=event.clientY;
 alert("X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onmousedown="show_coords(event)">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is in the body , i dont know how to make it work to give me the coordinates everywhere on the page not only in the paragraph

<body>

      <div id="x">x</div>
      <div id="y">y</div>
      <p onmousedown="show_coords(event)">Click this paragraph, and an alert box will alert the x and y coordinates of the mouse pointer.    </p>

     </body>

Comment: I guess you have only the div in your body. Then, add the style "width:100%;height:100%" to the body. So it will cover entire window.

Comment: @user3503874 i have added the sample program for you. Try it. I have a given a border for your entire body to see how big it is. and just try removing that height:100% and check the same. You will understand it clearly then.

Comment: i added style to the body,but its not working on entire page.
this is my code now :
      '   function show_coords(event)
      {
       var x =event.clientX;
       var y=event.clientY;
       $("#click").html("X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y);
      return false;
       }
       <body 
        onmousedown="show_coords(event)">
        <div id="x">x</div>
        <div id="y">y</div>
        <div id="click"></div>
         </body>  '

Comment: i dont know how to write the code here , i tried ' '  Sry for that.

Comment: thats ok. did u add the style what i have given (with border). SO, you can ensure that your document is covering full window. Are you able to see the border? how big it is?

Comment: i added html { 
                width:100%;
         height:100%;


            }
and now it works.i wanna do some more things , ill be back in 30 min if u can still help me out .TY for now .